# 1st block of code works ok in Firefox, Chrome, IE & Edge, but IE & Edge run 2nd block prematurely

Tags: javascript

The following two blocks of code work okay in Firefox & Chrome and in IE & Edge.  The first block expands the an image to fill the screen when clicked on and the second block shrinks the image again when clicked a second time.

The problem is that although the first block of code expands the image in all four browsers, IE & Edge (unlike Firefox & Chrome) also immediately run the second block without waiting for the second click. How do I stop these two browsers doing that?

I tried adding a semicolon at the end of each block to no avail.

Partial code follows:

Block One - Expand image to fullscreen

```
var globalreqfullscreen = getreqfullscreen() 
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target
    if (target.classList.contains('canfullscreen')){
    globalreqfullscreen.call(target)
    }
}, false)
```

Block Two - Shrink expanded image

```
var globalexitfullscreen = getexitfullscreen() 
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    var target = e.target
    if (target.classList.contains('canfullscreen')){
   globalexitfullscreen.call(document)
}
}, false)
```

Thanks for the three comments posted overnight:

I have also tried a toggling approach with Block 3 replacing Blocks 1 & 2. This expands with all four browsers but will not close with a second click. However, if I take out the second to last last } then Firefox & Chrome still expand and contract with separate clicks, but IE and Edge expand and immediately contract with the initial click.  I appear to have gone full circle :-(

Block Three - A toggling approach

```
var globalreqfullscreen = getreqfullscreen() // get supported ver of requestFullscreen()
var globalexitfullscreen = getexitfullscreen() // get supported ver of document.exitFullscreen()
var globalfullscreenelement = fullscreenelement() // get supported ver of document.fullscreenElement()

document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
var target = e.target
if (target.classList.contains('canfullscreen')){
  if (globalfullscreenelement == null){ // if browser is currently not in full screen 
        globalreqfullscreen.call(target)
    }
    else{
        globalexitfullscreen.call(document)
    }
}
```

}, false)

UPDATE: I now have a toggle setup that works for all four browsers. Will update this after I pay around with it a bit more. Thanks everyone, Don

Comment: There's nothing in the click handlers that would restrict them to *not* run at the same time, so in theory IE's behavior is correct.

Comment: Can you post more context around where the second snippet is run?

Comment: Since you are attempting to implement a sort of TOGGLE behavior, it would make sense that you reflect this in a sort of TOGGLE function, meaning, a single function that checks the status of the image (or a flag) and then either expands or shrinks the image. This approach would not only solve your issue but also would be more elegant (at least in my opinion of course).

Comment: in your block3, you need to update your FSElement at every call, since you wrapped this prop in a custom function, so do `if(fullscreenelement())`.